# Zalando postgres operator acces to cluster from outside in k8s

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I have installed postgres cluster Zalando postgres operator https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator
How can I get access to postgres database from outside?
I tried to change cluster service type from ClusterIP to NodePort, but it is overwritten automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The process is explained here:
https://postgres-operator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/

You need 2 steps.

1. script that opens up and forwards a port to your local machine.

I created a script called `set_dbforwarding.sh`.  You need
to change the names in the script to your cluster names and settings!
so `cdf-cluster`  should become `yourclustername`.

```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
     
    set -u   # crash on missing env variables
    set -e   # stop on any error
    set -x   # print what we are doing
     
    export NAMESPACE=$1
     
    export PGMASTER=$(kubectl -n cdf-acc get pods -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name} -l application=spilo,cluster-name=cdf-cluster,spilo-role=m
    
    # PGMASTER should be now the master node. There are cases under failover
    # that you should connect to a different node in your cluster.
    # If you want to change something you should always connect to the master.
    # otherwise you get 
     
    # set up port forward
    kubectl -n $NAMESPACE port-forward $PGMASTER 6432:5432
     
    # get the password..it is printend in your terminal
    # so you can use it in your db tool of choice.
    export PGPASSWORD=$(kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get secret cdf.cdf-cluster.credentials.postgresql.acid.zalan.do -o 'jsonpath={.data.password}' | b
    export PGSSLMODE=require
```

executed like:

```
     ./set_dbforwarding.sh yourclusternamespace
```

2. connect to your cluster with the correct credentials. `restore_db.sh` script.

   ```
     #!/usr/bin/env bash

     set -u   # crash on missing env variables
     set -e   # stop on any error
     set -x   # print what we are doing

     export NAMESPACE=$1  
     export DATABASE=$2  
     export DATABASEDUMP=$3  

     export PGMASTER=$(kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get pods -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name} -l application=spilo,cluster-name=cdf-cluster,spilo-rol
     export PGPASSWORD=$(kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get secret postgres.cdf-cluster.credentials.postgresql.acid.zalan.do -o 'jsonpath={.data.password}
     export PGSSLMODE=require  

     # examples you can run now the the above ENV variables set.

     # psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d cdf -p 6432  
     #cat ~/dumps/cbs_schema_wfs.sql | psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d cdf -p 6432

     # pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 6432 -d $2 -c $3  
     # data only  
     # pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 6432 -d $2 -a $3  
     # everything  
     pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -p 6432 -d $2 $3
   ```

used like

```
     ./restore_db.sh namespace databasename backup.gz
```

3. Tip if you are using a Database tool like DBbeaver make sure to check the keep-alive box every 5 seconds or so. Or the connection will be dropped.
   The keep alive will keep it open. But the settings is rather hidden on DBBeaver.

   editconnection -> connectionsettings -> initialization -> Keep-Alive.